# Amplify Auth server side returning signInUserSession:null when sign in

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

so I'm facing an error when I try to use MFA on server side Amplify, I'm always getting this error "User is not authenticated", I noticed that it's because when I'm using the function `Auth.signIn(name, password, { _id, roles, organizations });`, is returning an object but the key `signInUserSession` is null, but the key `Session` is not, and that's why when I call the method `Auth.setupTOTP(user);` is returning this error.
So let me show you how is the config of the amplify auth:

```
Auth.configure({
  region: this.authConfig.region,
  userPoolId: this.authConfig.userPoolId,
  userPoolWebClientId: this.authConfig.clientId,
  storage: NodeLocalStorage,
  oauth: {},
});
```

Difficult to say, I'm not sure if there's a missing config inside AWS cognito, or a bug from amplify or wtf is going on, haha thanks so much for your help.